# Rails Simple Form Bootstrap - checkbox inline vertical alignment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app with simple form and bootstrap.

I have checkbox elements in my form. I want to align the check box to be vertically aligned with the content in other fields. At the moment the check box is further left than the rest of the content in other fields.

For example:

```
<%= f.input :experiment, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Do you want experiment logs or methods?'  %>
```

Does anyone know how to make the vertical alignment uniform so that checkboxes are not out to the left of the rest of the form elements?

Thank you

To expand on the above,

I'd like the checkbox to be left aligned in line with the left edge of the other form elements. At the moment, it is further left (like there is some kind of negative margin on that check box element).

I'd like all three of these field inputs to be flush at the left alignment. At the moment, the check box in the two boolean elements is further left than the third text field:

```
<%= f.input :survey, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Do you need survey responses?'  %>
<br><br>


    <%= f.input :survey_link, label: 'Where is your survey?', :label_html => { :class => 'question-data' }, placeholder: 'Include a link to your survey', :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 650px; margin-top: 20px',  class: 'response-project'} %>

<br>

<%= f.input :experiment, :as => :boolean, :label => false, inline_label: 'Do you want experiment logs or methods?'  %>
```

Comment: It would be great if you show us the demo. It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi - I have added example in the above. The two checkbox elements are further to the left of the text input element. I'd like them all to be flush

Answer (score 0):

As doc suggested here http://montrezorro.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/ You should have `data-label` in your input so change your input like this:

```
<%= f.input :experiment, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :input_html => { :'data-label' => 'Do you want experiment logs or methods?' }   %>
```

If you want prepend then :

```
<%= f.input :experiment, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :input_html => { :'data-label-prepend' => 'Do you want experiment logs or methods?' }   %>
```

Comment: Hi Nitin, I'm afraid I get an error when I tried this, which reads: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>

Comment: Hi there - no it didn't work. It doesn't display the label at all and the alignment of the box is still to the left of all the other input elements in the form. Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know what that means. There is a box and no text when I use the above prepend line. Thanks very much for trying.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom wrapper like this:

```
  config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2' do |ba|
      ba.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'checkbox' do |baa|
        baa.use :input
      end
      #ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end
```

In my case I wanted a simple inline checkbox with the label to the right to place below another form element.  You may need to play with the `col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2`.  This goes in your SimpleForm initializer (or make a separate one line I did to avoid breaking things in the original).  Also you need to restart your app to see the changes take effect.